# Ansible S3 module not pulling all objects from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I have a bucket in S3 , which is having many objects. I am using ansible to download the artifacts . Now there is something strange going on and i am not really sure whats wrong here.

The play i am using firsts lists all the object:

```
- name: List
  s3:
     bucket: '{{ s3_bucket }}'
     mode: list
     region: '{{ s3_region }}'
     profile: '{{ s3_profile }}'
     encrypt: no
```

Pretty nice and simple,, but this only fetches some of the objects and not all the object from the S3 bucket.

I am not sure why is this is happening. Can someone help me find why i am not able

Comment: Run the play with debug enabled `-vvv`. Maybe you are running into a limit. IMHO Ansible is not the right tool for downloading huge amounts of data from S3. Triggering a s3cmd process from Ansible would be my choice.

Comment: the things is i just want to download a particular object , which is not big, i see the debug output and i can see that the it contains only some of the objects , but when i try with awscli  , i see all the things.. what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The Ansible [s3 module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html) has since Ansible version 2.0 a `max_keys` parameter.

> Max number of results to return in list mode, set this if you want to retrieve fewer than the default 1000 keys.

Even so so it is not explicitly noted I assume from the note in the documentation that 1000 keys is the maximum amount keys the `s3` module is capable of retrieving.

So to download huge amounts of data from s3 with Ansible it is probably better to trigger an `s3cmd` from Ansible.

Comment: Note: the updated link to Ansible S3 module is https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html